# How To Restrict Files Uploaded To SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload

We have a requirement to restrict some files uploaded to SharePoint Online?

Previously with SharePoint On-Premises we could utilise the blocked file types in the admin console but that is not available in SharePoint Online.

It doesn't seem possible through Rights Management either.

From the documentation here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3 it is possible to upload all files.

As an example, we would like to restrict .exe files from upload.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, There is no OOTB functionality with SharePoint Online to restrict specific file extensions in SharePoint Online.

**Workaround:**

You can create workflow that will auto-runs on each file upload and if it doesn't match the given type or extension (.exe in your case), auto-delete that document

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB solution for this. But you can restrict this at tenant level although It works only with the OneDrive and not with the document Library.

[MSDN Ref](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/Set-SPOTenantSyncClientRestriction?view=sharepoint-ps)

Alternatively, As Anil suggested, you can write a workflow which runs on Item_Created. This will verify the file extension and delete it based on your rules

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB solution to restrict file type when uploading into library.
You could create an event receiver to check file type and then write logic to prevent uploading.